# UINavigationButton lost UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swipe, uibarbuttonitem

I have navigationview controller with two pages, on every page i have right button (right navigation item in navigation bar).
I navigate from the first view controller to second, then from the second view controller make back swipe to the first and keep second view controller on the screen and then move to the second, then with the back button move to the first view controller. So at navigation bar at the first view controller my right bar button lost target.
So i catch sendAction at my application and see another one:

```
2015-09-28 14:51:30.724 myApp[1333:450524] ***sendAction:to:(null) from:<UINavigationButton: 0x1389361d0; frame = (951 -1; 64 43); opaque
= NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1377a3210>>
```

If do not swipe views - it works great and in the log i can see:

```
2015-09-28 14:50:52.228 myApp[1333:450524] ***sendAction:to:<UIBarButtonItem: 0x13772b500> from:<UINavigationButton: 0x1375630e0; frame = (951 -1; 64 43); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x13778ac70>>
2015-09-28 14:50:52.229 myApp[1333:450524] ***sendAction:to:<myFirstViewController: 0x137739cb0> from:<UIBarButtonItem: 0x13772b500>
```

So after swipe UINavigationButton lost UIBarButtonItem.
I don't have any idea.
All bindings i made at StoryBoard in designer.

Comment: show your swipe action method

Comment: This is not my swipe method. This is standard iOS way for back navigation in navigation controller.

Comment: i dont understand why you mentioned the word swipe!!!!